# How to view memory bandwidth in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, memory

I want to view the memory bandwidth of the installed physical memory on CentOS and Ubuntu. How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install dmidecode on CentOS (not sure about Ubuntu) and then as root call `dmidecode --type 17` then look through the out to see the kind of ram you have.
Though beware, ive experienced it not being 100% accurate.

An alternative way to do it would be to run a benchmark. Stream benchmark can work on CentOS.